# Why do I get ProviderMismatchException when I try to .relativize() a Path against another Path?

Tags: java, java-7, java.nio.file

[note: self answered question]

I have opened a `FileSystem` to a zip file using java.nio. I have gotten a `Path` from that filesystem:

```
final Path zipPath = zipfs.getPath("path/into/zip");
```

Now I have a directory on the local filesystem which I have obtained using:

```
final Path localDir = Paths.get("/local/dir")
```

I want to test whether `/local/dir/path/into/zip` exists, so I check its existence using:

```
Files.exists(localDir.resolve(zipPath))
```

but I get a `ProviderMismatchException`. Why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 17):

This behaviour is documented, albeit it is not very visible. You have to delve into the [`java.nio.file` package description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/compact1-package-summary.html) to see, right at the end, that:

> Unless otherwise noted, invoking a method of any class or interface in this package created by one provider with a parameter that is an object created by another provider, will throw ProviderMismatchException.

The reasons for this behaviour may not be obvious, but consider for instance that two filesystems can define a [different separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getSeparator--).

There is no method in the JDK which will help you there. If your filesystems use the same separator then you can work around this using:

```
path1.resolve(path2.toString())
```

Otherwise this utility method can help:

```
public static Path pathTransform(final FileSystem fs, final Path path)
{
    Path ret = fs.getPath(path.isAbsolute() ? fs.getSeparator() : "");
    for (final Path component: path)
        ret = ret.resolve(component.getFileName().toString());
    return ret;
}
```

Then the above can be written as:

```
final Path localPath = pathTransform(localDir.getFileSystem(), zipPath);
Files.exists(localDir.resolve(localPath));
```

Comment: I'm unable to get this working. Why is a `component` variable in the loop never used? And you forgot to set return type to `Path` and add brackets after `isAbsolute()` and `getSeparator()`.

Comment: So, `ret` is a `Path` of one provider and `path` of another. Then you still get `ProviderMismatchException` if you want to `resolve` them using `component.getFileName()` which returns `Path`, don't you?

Comment: @Genhis *sigh* I forgot `.toString()` after `.getFileName()`